# How to take input argument and convert that into a string (Python)

Tags: python, matplotlib

In my code, I am reading an image, and then plotting it with matplot. In my *plotColor* function, I want to create a plt.title(image) where the image that I pass (lena or link) will be displayed as a title. 
So if I do plotColor(lena), I will get a plt of lena with lena as a title. 
All my pictures are showing correctly with this code and I know I can pass a second literal string argument and use that, but I was wondering if there was a way to accomplish this by passing only 1 argument.

```
def plotColor(image):
    plt.figure()
    plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
    plt.title("image")

lena = cv2.imread("lena.png")
link = cv2.imread("link.png")

plotColor(lena)
plotColor(link)
```

Thanks!

**EDIT** 
I'm having issues with calling upon that path in subsequent functions I've created. (This is based on the proposed solution below)

```
def grayScale(image):
    output = cv2.cvtColor(image.image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    return output
def plotGrayscale(image):
    plt.figure()
    plt.imshow(image.image, cmap='gray')
#     plt.title(image.path)
```

image.path cannot be added when I try: `plotGrayscale(grayScale(lena))` so I can't make the title on the output image.

Answer (score 0):

The proposed solution isn't a robust way to achieve what you want; it relies on the fact that `lena` and `link` are defined globally. If they moved into another function, for example, then you wouldn't be able to `eval()` those strings. Additionally it's not really necessary to execute strings as code just to make a string available. If you want to pass a single object around with more than one piece of data/information, simply create a class to hold both things and just pass instances of that class around. Here's a simple example:

```py
class PathedImage:
    def __init__(self, path):
        self.image = cv2.imread(path)
        self.path = path

def plotColor(image):
    plt.figure()
    plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(image.image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
    plt.title(image.path)

lena = PathedImage("lena.png")
link = PathedImage("link.png")

plotColor(lena)
plotColor(link)
```

You can get much more fancy here if you wanted; for example, a `PathedImage` could subclass a numpy array so that it acts exactly like a numpy array, but with a `name` or `path` attribute added, for example.

Comment: I tried this solution for other parts of my code (when i wanted to plot a grayscale image) and I was having issues because the PathedImage path wasn't being passed through the output and so I couldn't call upon that later to get the image name. I've added the rest of the code as an edit to my question.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to achieve what you want is passing the file name as a parameter to your function and opening the image file inside the function. That way, you have the file name string available to clean it up and make it your image title. You can also add a parameter to have a single plotting function and select whether you want to plot color or grayscale images:

```
import os
def plotImage(file, grayscale=False):
    image = cv2.imread(file)
    filename = os.path.basename(file).split('.')[0]
    plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY if grayscale else cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
    plt.title(filename)

plotImage("lena.png") # plot color image
plotImage("link.png", grayscale=True) # plot grayscale image
```